# remove hidden (display:none) html tags in php

Tags: php, regex, strip-tags

I need a PHP regex that will remove  (with display:none in their style) from a html code sequence. I tried exploding it and working it out but it turns out to be a mess.
For example the html code below

```
 <span>
<span style="display: inline">69</span>
<span style="display:none">113</span>
<span></span>
<span class="" style="">.</span>
<span style="display: inline">86</span>
<span style="display:none">59</span>
<span></span>
.206
<span></span>
.143
</span>
```

should turn out like this:

```
<span>
<span style="display: inline">69</span>
<span></span>
<span class="" style="">.</span>
<span style="display: inline">86</span>
<span></span>
.206
<span></span>
.143
</span>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Do **NOT** use regexes to manipulate html. You'll just end up causing yourself massive amounts of grief, especially if the html is even slightly malformed. Use DOM instead: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/118068

Comment: Just a tip on question-asking: when you said something about removing hidden, I scanned your code for "hidden" and was very confused when I didn't find it. I had to start from the top and see that you were referring to `display: none` -- if `display: none` is what you mean, just say that.

Comment: @DragoonWraith you know what I meant... do you?

Comment: @RazvanPandor: no one here is being paid to help anybody. If you want useful answers, it is very much in your best interest to make your question clear and easy to answer. I did *not* know what you meant until I went back and read it a second time. Many users would not have given you that second read-through.

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML is not a regular language and therefor cannot be parsed by regular expressions.

You can use this though and then use what it returns with php:

http://api.jquery.com/remove/

```
$("span[style='display:none']").remove();
```

If you don't want to do that, you can use dom and the removeChild function: http://php.net/manual/en/domnode.removechild.php

Comment: OP wants to do it in php, but otherwise this would be the correct method.

Comment: this was my second option, I hoped theres a quicker regex method. Thanks!